# How to convert a local branch to a remote branch in Git?

Tags: git, github

Currently I have a remote branch in Git named "master" and a local branch named "sample". Now I want to the local branch "sample" to be the remote branch instead of "master" being so. Is there a way to do so?

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, what cloud environment are you using?

Comment: Please share with us the output of `git remote --all`.

Comment: Define what *you* mean by local and remote. "Remote branch" typically means a copy of the commits existing in a branch in a remote repository. You can *push* `sample` to the remote repository, which makes your local `sample` into a tracking branch for the remote `sample`.

Comment: To make a local branch a remote branch, you just switch hosts.  Swap laptops with your neighbor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

1. First, push the new default to GitHub

   ```
   git push -u origin sample
   ```
2. Then, in GitHub, open the repository and click on the branches link.

   Click on the Change Default Branch button and then select the new default branch.

You will now be able to delete the old remote master with

```
git push origin :master
```

Comment: Nobody said anything about GitHub though.

Comment: @poke it has a github tag

Answer (score 1):

That is not how branches work. Local branches and remote branches are a different set that *may* be linked but don’t have to. The remote branches are prefixed with the remote name, e.g. `origin/master` and correspond to the `master` branch that is *local on the remote*.

Often, you will have a local branch that tracks a remote branch. E.g. your local `master` branch may be tracking the remote `origin/master` branch which means that you will push to and pull from that branch by default. But both branches are still actual branches that independently refer to commits in the history.

But if you have a local branch `sample` and want to publish that *to the remote* as “sample”, then you can push it to the remote:

```
git push origin sample
```

This will push the local `sample` branch to the remote, creating a *local* branch *on the remote*, and adding a *remote branch* to your repository called `origin/sample` that represents the remote’s local branch.

Answer (score 1):

for making the local branch to remote branch kindly use

```
git push --set-upstream origin sample
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing of you question makes it difficult to be certain, but I believe you are looking for:

```
git push --force origin sample:master
```

This does not make `sample` a remote branch.  It changes the `master` branch on the remote so that it now refers to the same commit that the local branch `sample` refers to.  Note that doing this is somewhat destructive.  The commit that `master` was referencing before this command is executed may no longer have any references and may thus be subject to deletion during the next garbage collection cycle. Always exercise `git push --force` with extreme caution.  Until you understand the branching model better, you may wish to refrain from executing this command.